# Google analytics in third party widget?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm working on a widget in pure JS which will be embedded into a host website. The widget isn't embedded with an iframe but just with DOM manipulation.

So in a host website (http://www.example.com), I inject a JS file from http://api.mywidget.com/embed.js. This JS file will do DOM manipulation to show the widget on the host website without any iframe. Hope I'm clear...

I want to add Google Analytics to this widget. I add Google Analytics like that:

```
(function() {

    mywidget.$.ready(function() {

        mywidget.run = function(o) {

            // ADD ANALYTICS
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['mywidget._setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x']);
            _gaq.push(['mywidget._trackPageview']);

            (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();

            ... other initialization ...
        };

        mywidget.run();
    });

}).call(this);
```

The google-analytics file is correctly injected. I can see it in the developer tools on Chrome. But no data is transmitted to Google Analytics.

When I created the Google Analytics account, the form asked me the website url so I put something like that http://api.mywidget.com but there is maybe a security which block me to inject it in another website. I don't known in fact.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented the Measurement Protocol (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference).